# Pass click events through a DOM layer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that is positioned to the bottom of the page and sits above everything on the page. I include a shadow to remove the harsh cutoff of the content below. However, I cannot click any of the links in the ".container" area since I'm technically clicking ontop of the shadow.

Is there a way to pass events through this div layer and be able to click links in the "container" div?

```
<div class="bottom-wrap">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <a href="http://www.google.com" class="#topButton">Click</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    // a bunch of content here
</div>
```

I've created this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aY2Ld/ which should help understand my problem.

Comment: No, not really. Better off just moving it infront of the shadow. It's possible to pass the click events through, but it's probably going to require more code than you're willing to write on your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add

```
pointer-events:none;
```

to your .bottom-wrap class in your CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/aY2Ld/1/

EDIT : you'll also need to add pointer-events:fill; to the .bottom class

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aY2Ld/4/

Comment: Then how does one click the "Click" anchor in that `<div class="bottom">` div? Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aY2Ld/3/)

Comment: try adding pointer-events: fill; to your .bottom class, it should work :)

Comment: Ahhhh... you are absolutely right.  If you change that in your fiddle, then you have the correct answer (as far as I am concerned).

Answer (score 2):

If browser support is not a probleme fore you, you can use the CSS properties [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/CSS/pointer-events)

```
.bottom-wrap {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

But to make the content inside active, you need to reset it like that :

```
.bottom-wrap .bottom {
    pointer-events:auto;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aY2Ld/5/

Comment: Then how does one click the "Click" anchor in that `<div class="bottom">` div? Try it in your fiddle -- Here, I added alerts to [this other fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aY2Ld/3/)

Comment: @gibberish What browser are you using, it work perfectly for me?

Comment: Google Chrome -- did you try the fiddle in my comment? The alert shows 'comment', not 'Hi' (clicking on the "CLICK" anchor should alert "Hi").

Answer (score 1):

You should implement your own event chain.

For example:

```
$('.shadow').click(function() {
    $('.under-shadow').trigger('click');
});
```

Althought it would work, I wouldn't recommend the use of `pointer-events:none;` since it isn't well supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the pointer-events to none; for the overlaying div. See this page for an example: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/