# Access div behind current div. Achieve hole in page to discover content

Tags: jquery, html, css

So basically I am trying to build this site, where there is a page with a bunch of stuff on it, and in order to find the stuff you need to search around the page using this sort of flashlight / tool thing to see what lies underneath. Here is the jsfiddle for a better example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pwneth/hj57k/1896/

CSS:

```
#tail {
border: 1000px solid #fff;
position: absolute;
float: left;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
z-index: 100;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
    $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
        $('#tail').css({
           left:  e.pageX - 1050,
           top:   e.pageY - 1050
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="content"></div>
 <div id="tail"></div>
```

Essentially what I want works except I want to be able to access the div that is behind the current one so that it can be clicked on and bring me to a new page. Is something like this possible? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771112/pass-click-events-through-a-dom-layer

Answer (score 0):

As @JonnySooter posted above in the comments, if your browser requirements don't include IE <= 10 (see: [caniuse pointer-events](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events)) you can use the style: `pointer-events: none;` and mouse events will be ignored on `tail`.

Otherwise, you could determine which elements are under the mouse position at the time of the click event.

Using the answer from this question: [find elements that are stacked under (visually) an element in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598953/find-elements-that-are-stacked-under-visually-an-element-in-jquery), you can determine which element should be clicked:

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/hj57k/1907/)</kbd>

HTML: (Modified to be sequence of DIV's)

```
<div>kjashkfjaiufaewhfejakdkskjashkfjaiufaiufaewhfejakdkskjashkfjaiufaewhf</div>
<div>kjashkfjaiufaewhfejakdkskjashkfjaiufaiufaewhfejakdkskjashkfjaiufaewhf</div>
…
<div id="tail"></div>
```

Code (works with jQuery 1.4.2 as in the OP's fiddle):

```
function GetAllElementsAt(x, y) {
    var $elements = $("body *").map(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var offset = $this.offset();
        var l = offset.left;
        var t = offset.top;
        var h = $this.height();
        var w = $this.width();

        var maxx = l + w;
        var maxy = t + h;

        return (y <= maxy && y >= t) && (x <= maxx && x >= l) ? $this : null;
    });

    return $elements;
}

// Change to '.on' in more recent version of jQuery
$('#tail').bind('click', function(evt) {
    var $elements = GetAllElementsAt(evt.pageX, evt.pageY);

    // In this example, "There can be only one" - the zero'th element will be
    // the clicked element
    alert("You clicked on div #" + ($($elements[0]).prevAll().length + 1));
});
```