# Capturing an event through a DOM layer that contains other event listeners

Tags: javascript, html, css

tldr; I want to have a button's event captured (click) even though it's under a DOM layer.

Here's my problem, I have a DOM layer that's relatively positioned and has a z-index set higher than 1, let's just say 2. That DOM layer is above the button (Button A) I'd like to have triggered when clicked. The reason that DOM layer is above the button (Button A) in question, is that the button (ShoreMore) across from it has another event that when clicked, opens a drawer of other little links.

Here's what I've tried:

1. I tried adding `pointer-events: none;` to the DOM layer above my button. problem is that while it now allows the button to be pressed, the DOM layer with the button that opens the drawer of other link no longer works. Suggested by [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771112/pass-click-events-through-a-dom-layer)
2. I also came across this little trick found on [this website.](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/) It essentially, hides the mask and rechecks the user's click coordinates and fires the event that is found within the coordinate. However, I found myself unsatisfied with the results, as I'm often given DOM that's unhelpful too specific or too broad based on the user's click. (e.g. getting the icon, text next to the icon, etc. of the Button).

For illustration purposes, here's what I have:

[image]

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div id="drawer" class="drawer">
    <div id="shield" class="shield"></div>
    <div id="expander" class="expander">
        <div class="inner">
            <ul>
                <li>links</li>
                <li>links</li>
                <li>links</li>
                <li>links</li>
                <li>links</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tab" class="tab" >
                <i class="icon"></i> Show More
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<span id="btnA" class="btn">
    <i class="icon"></i>
    <span>Button A</span>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.drawer {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.expander {
    position: relative;
    height: 28px;
    transition: height .2s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
}
```

I didn't include the javascript, but "Button A" and "Show More" have a click listener. They both work, but Button A is confirmed to work if pointer-events: none; is added to the CSS of the class "expander."

EDIT: spelling

Comment: In your illustration, which button is not working the way you want it to? "Close"?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. Button A

Comment: So BEFORE the tray moves down, you can't click "Button A" because it's below the blue outlined layer?

Comment: Before the tray moves down, I can't click "Button A", yes. The expander is above Button A due to the Show More button. @JCD

I want to be able to click Button A only when the tray is not expanded.

Comment: I think you're over complicating this design. Why not just have all those elements in a single layer, and do some visual manipulation with slideDown()/slideUp()?

Comment: Unfortunately, they've been separated due to the components doing separate things. Buddy wants them modular so that when Button A needs a change, only Button A's component is updated. Keep in mind, the DOM and illustration above is simplified to how it's finally rendered.

Comment: This whole thing is a little goofy but you could (fixed) position another (invisible) div inside the blue div, over Button A, and assign that the same listeners Button A has.

Comment: @St.G, I agree. However, it breaks the code independence my buddy wants for the two buttons as they do completely different things.

Comment: @bigbitecode Alternatively, break "show more" out of the blue div with absolute positioning; that will collapse the blue div to just the drawer, revealing Button A.

Comment: @St.G That's another great suggestion, but it introduces another component that really is a part of the tray component. :/ Thanks for the answer though, it's great for those who do not really care about "components." Unfortunately, my buddy does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use more absolute positioning.

The problem you're running into is that HTML elements, no matter their shape, end up as rectangles when rendered. Your blue outlined layer has a complex shape that's not strictly rectangular, but HTML doesn't care - it expands the layer's shape into a big rectangle to cover the parent element and all of its children elements, as you've correctly drawn in your diagram.

Absolute positioning helps prevent that from happening. Instead of leaving space for an element in the document flow, absolute positioning sort of pops the element out and positions it relative to its parent. The result is an element that doesn't expand the borders of its parent element, because it essentially takes up zero space in the normal document flow.

Consider the following example:

```js
$(function(){
  function slideDown(){
    this.innerHTML = "Close";
    $("#tray").animate({top: "50px"});
    $("#higher-button").off("click").on("click", slideUp);
  }
  function slideUp(){
    this.innerHTML = "Show More";
    $("#tray").animate({top: "0px"});
    $("#higher-button").off("click").on("click", slideDown);
  }

  $("#higher-button").on("click", slideDown);
  
  $("#lower-button").on("click", function(){
   alert("Lower button clicked.");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

#lower-button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}

#higher-button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #888888;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}

#tray {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  position: absolute;
}

#mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <div id="lower-button">Button A</div>
  <div id="tray">
    <div id="higher-button">Show More</div>
  </div>
  <div id="mask">Mask</div>
</div>
```

Absolute positioning lets you easily layer and position elements in a way that avoids them taking up excess space.

The caveat to all this is that absolute positioning can be pretty messy. Since it removes elements from the normal document flow, they don't take up any space, and it can wreak havok with your layouts. So use absolute positioning sparingly, for cases like this where you're building a UI element that you probably don't need taking up space in the layout anyway.

As always there are dozens of ways to solve this problem and this is only one possibility, but I hope it helps you figure out your own solution. Good luck!

Edit: Note you don't necessarily need to make *all* of the UI elements absolutely positioned, only the ones you need in order to manage the document flow. For example, the parent UI element could still be relatively positioned, and you just "pop out" the individual UI components. You still need to manually manage the size of the parent UI container, because absolutely positioned elements take up zero space in the flow. jsfiddle.net/v2646v41

Comment: I really appreciate the answer you gave me, but unfortunately, absolute positioning will break a lot of things. :( The illustration I gave is simplified and you did give a great example of how to achieve it, but as you have mentioned, there are other layout objects I have omitted that depend on the flow. A great answer, nonetheless for those who do not depend too much on absolute positioning.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to make *all* of the UI elements absolutely positioned, only the ones you need in order to manage the document flow. For example, the parent UI element could still be relatively positioned, and you just "pop out" the individual UI components. You still need to manually manage the size of the parent UI container, because absolutely positioned elements take up zero space in the flow. https://jsfiddle.net/v2646v41/

Comment: ah, gotcha. Let me play around with this and report back on how it ends up. I'll edit this comment when I get my findings.

Comment: Turns out I can't edit a comment, but thanks JCD. I got a similar setup to this and it works. :) Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would be to change the z-index of Button A. When the drawer is closed, set it higher than the drawer's div, and when Show More is clicked, set the z-index underneath, then back above after the drawer has slid back under the mask.

Comment: This won't work in my current case because only the show more/close button is positioned absolute. However. if both buttons were positioned, yes, this solution works.

Comment: Why can't you use `position: relative` on Button A?